# Is there a way to force backtesting to calculate results based on the actual trigger price when an entry condition is met?

Tags: pine-script

Beginner at Pine here. I'm backtesting a custom strategy on a 4H chart with entry through market orders, and TV automatically takes the entry prices as the close of the candle when the entry condition is met (I've enabled "process orders on close"). On a 4H chart, there's often a significant difference between the price the entry was triggered at and the price at candle close so this is giving me very inaccurate results in the strategy tester.

Is there a way to force backtesting to calculate based on the trigger price when the entry was triggered? I want entry prices to be the same way that stop loss and take price prices can be set at exact prices even if they're not at OHLC. The system obviously allows for mid-candle exits, so not why also mid-candle entries?

A limit order doesn't work because it only applies it from the next candle onward after the entry condition is met on the previous price and often the order in the strategy just doesn't fill.

I could look into MTF, but the same issue would still apply even in a lower tf candle. Also, the entry condition is defined by mutable variables, so I'm unable to use a security function to pull those values anyway, because the security function doesn't allow mutable variables as arguments.

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you want now.

Comment: @AndreyD - Ok thanks.